# Looking for data on Eastern European scientists working in Western Europe

Tags: data-request, migration

I would like to have statistics on Eastern European scientists working in Western Europe.

I have found some related papers like [Brain Drain in the European Union: Facts & Figures](http://www.bridgingeurope.net/uploads/8/1/7/1/8171506/wp4_rethink_edu_braindrain_nedeljkovic.pdf) or [Emigration from Eastern Europe with a Focus on Brain Drain](http://pure.au.dk/portal/files/75142686/Luiza_Ionescu_Emigration_from_Eastern_Europe_with_a_focus_on_Brain_Drain.pdf) but these do not contain data material for knowing how many scientists move from Eastern Europe to Western Europe.

Could you help me finding a reliable data source on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The German Federal Statistics Office was so kind to provide me data on the issue in Germany:

https://www.destatis.de/DE/Publikationen/Thematisch/BildungForschungKultur/Hochschulen/PersonalHochschulen.html

On page 190, you will find the table

> 13 Wissenschaftliches und künstlerisches Personal nach Herkunftsländern und Fächergruppen der fachlichen Zugehörigkeit

that is, scientific and art personnel according to their original country and per job area.